# Find the two numbers that appear only once - divide and conquer

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, bit-manipulation, divide-and-conquer

Given an array in which each element appears twice, I have to find which two numbers of the array appear only once. Maximum additional memory is O(1).

I have found this amazing solution: https://medium.com/@gurupad93/two-numbers-that-appear-once-b89e92a9334b

The problem is that my solution should be *divide and conquer*, and my understanding is that the solution I found is not.

I know how to solve this problem with *divide and conquer* when the element appearing once is just one. Here, I wouldn't know how to divide the array recursively to be honest.

Any suggestions?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Sounds like homework to me. So maybe questions regarding the task to perform should be directed to the homework instructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the numbers are positive integers. The list has an even number of elements. You compute the average and divide the list into two sublists, below and above average. Then either both have an odd number of elements or both an even. In the odd case you know that each sublist contains one singleton, and you solve the one-singleton problem for each of them. In the even case you know that one of the sublists has no singleton, i.e. is paired, while the other has two. You decide which one is paired and continue working on the other one, recursively solving the two-singleton problem.

If the integers are represented in standard binary you can XOR all of them to decide whether they are paired. Otherwise, if they are represented in BCD, floating point or whatever where the representative isn't unique, you can use the following test:
A list of integers is paired if and only if the product of all the elements is a square. Compute exp( 1/2 sum( log xi ) ) and if it's integral the list is paired, otherwise not.

But the solution in the link is admittedly much nicer than this.

Comment: I don't understand your second paragraph but the algorithm in first paragraph seems right - as long as you're extremely careful about boundary conditions when coding.  Boundary conditions are notoriously tricky for quicksort-like algorithms, and could be worse here because of the way of choosing the partition value (which will include rounding).  I'm wondering why you bothered to answer when you think the question isn't deserving of an upvote?

Comment: @davidbak I have upvoted it now. Nice problem. And the linked solution is even nicer.

Comment: I was finally able to solve it myself, this is my solution, I would appreciate any feedback: I divide the array in two, smaller and bigger elements than the median. I check with the algorithm for founding one element in both. Two options, if both of the results are on the same sub-arrays (both on left or both right), one of the two subarray's result will be 0, so I discard it and continue recursively. Other option, they are separated, in this case, neither result will be 0, and the two results of the one-time algorithm will be exactly the two numbers. I added an answer to better explain.

Answer (score 0):

Choose the first bit.

Separate numbers with this bit set and numbers with this bit zero.

You can use routine like partition in quick sort - find the leftmost number with one bit, find the rightmost number with zero bit, exchange them, continue until left and right indexes meet.

Treat the left part and the right part, considering the next bit.

Do this recursively with next bits until part size becomes 1 or 2.

In the first case you have found one of needed numbers.

In the second case check whether numbers are distinct.

---

I hope these clues might help to realize possible divide and conquer approach.

Comment: Seems reasonable for divide&conquer.  I'm wondering why you bothered to answer when you think the question isn't deserving of an upvote?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find an algorithm to my question:

I find the median of the array and use partition to have all the smaller elements on the left of the median and all the greater elements on the right.

I have an algorithm that is able to return when the element appearing once is only one (using XOR on all elements). If there is no element appearing only once, the XOR result is 0.

I run this algorithm on both of the two subarray, two options:

- If the algorithm outputs 0 on one array, then for sure the element is not in this subarray, and we call the function recursively on the other half.
- If (and only if) the algorithm outputs two numbers different than 0, it means the results got separated in the arrays. In this case, these two numbers will also be the results of the problem.

Note that there are no other options than these two.

Space Complexity is O(1)

Time Complexity: We have some operations that cost O(n), we divide at each iteration half of the array, we get:

T(n) = T(n/2) + O(n) -> (Master Theorem) -> O(n)

Comment: Isn't this @Henrik4's answer?

Comment: It's very similar to mine. If you arrived at it independently it's well done.

Comment: Yes, it's very similar! One note to my solution, if the result is 0 I must also check the amount of elements is even, this is because also the number 0 itself can be a result value. The cost is O(n) meant the cost of the whole implementation, I edited to make it clearer

Comment: @saraspagno You mean 0 can be a singleton? Exclude that by adding 1 to all the numbers before you go.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be divided in tree structure (similar to the tree structure of merge sort) and each partition returns the xor value of its elements to the parent. In this way, we obtain the xor value of two numbers which appear only once in the array.

From the problem, it is clear that the xor value has at at-least one non-zero bit.

Let us assume the xor value is **X** and its **i**-th bit is non-zero.

Now again we divide the problem in tree structure and consider elements, whose **i**-th bit is set, for the xor-computation. This value is returned to the parent. The root node will get the xor-value of the elements whose **i**-th bit is set. Let us call this value Y.

Hence, the two numbers are **Y** and **X xor Y**.